# PoseModule.py Method detector.findAngle ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, deep-learning, mediapipe, pose-estimation, cvzone

i have a problem using PoseModule in Pose Estimation app

```
while True:
    img = detector.findPose(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img, False)
    if len(lmList) != 0:
        detector.findAngle(img, 11, 13, 15)
```

And i have this message:

```
---> 17         detector.findAngle(img, 11, 13, 15)
     18 
     19     cv2.imshow("image", img)

C:\ml\pushupindi\PoseModule.py in findAngle(self, img, p1, p2, p3, draw)
     96 
     97         # Get the landmarks
---> 98         x1, y1 = self.lmList[p1][1:3]
     99         x2, y2 = self.lmList[p2][1:3]
    100         x3, y3 = self.lmList[p3][1:3]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I know that is an error of vars quantity, but i cant solved it ¿Any idea? Thanks